# How to use value of imeactionId

Tags: android

I am trying to set my own value to `imeActionId` and then comparing the same to the `actionId` in the `onEditorAction`. But the `actionId` in the method repeatedly returns 0.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textUri"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:imeActionId="666" 
        android:imeActionLabel="google"/>
```

And the following is my `onEditorAction`:

```
et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("myid iss", "" + actionId);

        if(actionId == 666)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://" + v.getText().toString()));

            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `actionId` is coming to be 0 every time irrespective of the value in the XML.
How do I use my defined `imeActionId` to compare with `actionId`.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for late reply. Still posting my answer for the benefit of others. Actually, each and every imeoptions got a unqiueId. In order perform your task, you can make use of below working code.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
        //Perform your Actions here.

    }
    return handled;
   }
});
```

For more info, you can refer this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html). Hope you find this answer usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Android recognises only specific actions which affect the appearance of soft keyboard (e.g. presence of DONE button). All such actions are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_GO) and neither has code 666. :)

What do you need a custom action for? To know where it comes from? Then just check view id:

```
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.editText2) {
                // Whatever ...
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

This will certainly work!

Comment: I am doing this to replace actionId like EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO with my own id. i know i can get the id of the view generating the action.kindly update if you know how to check for my own defined imeActionId.

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` instead works for me:

```
<com.fiverr.fiverr.Views.FVREditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:imeActionLabel="Create"
        android:imeActionId="@integer/editor_create_action_id"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="2"/>
```

And in code:

```
setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            customActionId = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.editor_create_action_id)
            if (actionId == customActionId) {
                onDonePressedRunnable.run();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

// this is working for me

1- remove `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` from the xml

2- check also for `IME_NULL` value since all these actions are considered as special keys, for example:

```
 if(actionId==666 || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL){
    ...
 }
```

3- also its a better practice is to keep everything in resources files not hardcoded, so for example create a resource file in the values folder call it ids.xml, and here how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="r_login" format="integer">1001</item>
</resources>
```

and then your layout xml file should look like:

```
android:imeActionId="@id/r_browse"
```

and your activity code  should look like:

```
if(actionId==R.id.r_browse || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL){
   ...
}
```

Cheers ;)